# Swift changed DatePicker Date to Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, datepicker, firebase-realtime-database

In my app, you click a button and the activity name and activity location is added to Firebase. I also want to add a selected time that you will be doing the activity to Firebase as well. To do this, I have created a DatePicker to pop up upon clicking the button, I have also managed to convert this to a string and upload to Firebase.

The issue I am having is the time that it uploads to Firebase is always the current time, am I right in saying I need to add an action to the DatePicker which will allow the selected time to be uploaded? If so how do I go about this?

```
 func handleAddAgenda(){

    var datePicker: UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.DateAndTime
    //datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dateChanged), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 460)
    datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    addSubview(datePicker)

    class ActDate: NSObject {
        var date: String?
    }

    var actDate: ActDate?

    if actDate == nil {
        actDate = ActDate()
    }


    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
    actDate?.date = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)
    print(datePicker.date)

    let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(userID!).child("Agenda")
    let childRef = ref.childByAutoId()
    let values = ["activity": activityName.text!, "location": distance.text!, "date": actDate!.date!]
    childRef.updateChildValues(values)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to add some action method to update the values when the datePicker date is selected. This will only work of course if you make the date picker a property of the whole class in order to grab the datePicker.date in the new method.

Something like this in viewDidLoad:

```
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.DateAndTime
datePicker.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 460)
datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
myDatePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dateChanged), for: .valueChanged)
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a"
actDate?.date = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)
```

Then you can have your `handleAgenda` simplified to this:

```
func handleAddAgenda(){
    addSubview(datePicker)
    print(datePicker.date)
}
```

And finally make the FireBase updates in the method:

```
func dateChanged() {
     if let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid {
         let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(userID).child("Agenda")
         let childRef = ref.childByAutoId()
         if let activityName = activityName.text, let distance = distance.text, let date = datePicker.date {
             let values = ["activity": activityName, "location": distance, "date": date]
             childRef.updateChildValues(values)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am receiving the 'unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value' using this method. Any idea where i could be going wrong?

Comment: It might be that you have not initialized `actDate` anywhere. Or it might be one of the force unwrapped properties is nil. In general, unless you are 100% sure the value of a property exists and its not nil, you should not use ! to force unwrapit. Making sure `userID`, `activityName.text`, `distance.text` and `actDate.date` are not nil before you force unwrap them would solve this. Or even better use optional unwrapping before you use the values. See my updated answer :)